# How Do I Use a Nested If-Else Statement within a For-Loop? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

For a take-home exercise, I have to write a function that will loop through test answers to check to see if an answer includes a certain String.

checkForPlagarism(submissionsArray, string) takes in an array and a string. It's supposed to loop through all of the objects in the array and check to see if they contain some string. But it seems to only return "false" after the first loop. When I pass in "Metaphase" as the string, for example, it returns "true". If I pass in the exact response of any other questions in the array, it returns "false" even when it should return "true". Here is my REPL: https://repl.it/@clamquarter/Take-Home-Science-Quiz#index.js

What am I doing wrong?

```
const submissions = [
      {
        question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
        response: 'Metaphase',
        isCorrect: true,
        isEssayQuestion: false
      }
    //and so on...
    ]
    
function checkForPlagiarism(submissionsArray, string) {
  for (let i = 0; i < submissionsArray.length; i++) {
    if (submissionsArray[i].response.includes(string)) {
    return true
    } 
      else {
        return false
      } 
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You should not `return false` until **after** the `for` loop completes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: btw, please change the name of the function to reflect the result, like `isPlagiarism`. `check...` is nice, but how do you interpret the result of it?

Comment: @NinaScholz if it were up to me, I would. But this is a take-home school assignment, so I can't change the function name.

Comment: @Pointy that was all! Thank you so much. I suppose it was more of a habit I'd taken from Swift. That, and I usually don't use if-else nested inside loops. Again! Thank you! If you give an official answer, I'll vote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return statements will exit a for loop. What's happening here is that your loop checks `submissionsArray[0]` and evaluates to `true` or `false` and exits the loop. `checkForPlagiarism` returns whatever `submissionsArray[0]` evaluated to.

To fix this, remove your else condition and have `checkForPlagiarism` return `false` when the loop completes.

Here's what that looks like:

```
function checkForPlagiarism(submissionsArray, string) {
  for (let i = 0; i < submissionsArray.length; i++) {
    if (submissionsArray[i].response.includes(string)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"You should not return false until after the for loop completes." - @Pointy